# Log file is not showing milliseconds of a timestamp

Tags: c#

I have the following log to a text file method:
I wanted to include a time stamp like this (2014-01-23 09:42:20.020 AM)
but when I look at my log file it doesn't include the .020 time. Did I miss to format something?

```
// Build timestamp string
var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string timeStampString =   currentDateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmssms");

// Build filename  messages, concat timestamp and .txt extension.
string debugFileName = "C:\\Test" + timeStampString  + ".txt";
var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
// Write to the file:
inboundMessageLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("TimeStampString = {0}", timeStampString);
inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("Inbound message = {0}", strMessage);
inboundMessageLog.Close();
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**

This format:

```
   string  timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt") or .fff tt;
```

didn't work for me. I see my logs only when I use

```
   string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd hhmmss");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem :** You are using `ms` to represent the Milliseconds.

**Solution :** there is no custom format `ms` 
You need to use `fff` to represent `MilliSeconds`

> **fff** The milliseconds in a date and time value.

if you want to get the Date and Time in the format of `(2014-01-23 09:42:20.020 AM)`

You need to use  this format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt`

Try This:

```
string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff tt");
```

**EDIT :** if you want custome format as `dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss:fff`

Try This:

```
string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss:fff tt");
```

**Explanation:**

[`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -  **Year** in 4 digits
[`MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Month**  in two digits
[`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Date** in two digits

[`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Hours** in two digits.
[`mm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Minutes** in two digits.
[`ss`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **Seconds**  in two digits.

[`fff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  -  **Milliseconds**
[`tt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   -  **AM** or **PM**.

See this for more information : [DateTime custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Of note is that although you fixed the big flaw you didn't actually put it in the format he said he wanted it in (2014-01-23 09:42:20.020 AM).

Comment: @GrantWinney: absolutly :)

Comment: That works!! How can I change the formatting to dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss:fff?

Comment: @HXD: nothing you just replace the current format withold one :) see my edited answer

Comment: this format string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt") or .fff tt; didn't work for me. I see my logs only when I use   string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd hhmmss");

Comment: @HXD: it's not working? you said it's working? ok could you please edit your post with error message?

Comment: sorry for the confusion I said it works just for the big flaw part. added comment before looking at the format update you added.

Comment: @HXD: if you use this format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt` what it shows in log file.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I don't see the file at all. I see nothing in my folder basically.

Comment: @HXD: ohh i see , you are creating text file also with same format using -> `string debugFileName = "C:\\Test" + timeStampString  + ".txt";` do you need to crete the textfile also using same format?

Comment: @HXD: i don't think you really need to save the file name using this format `(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt)` but you can save it your log, so i recommend you to use two different formats , one for filename another for file content, what do you say?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I gave it different names as you suggested. Now I see all my logs :) I mark is as answered!!